# To find norm and orthogonal complement of kernel of a linear functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Let $c_{00}$ be the vector space of all complex sequences having finitely many non-zero terms. Define the inner product $\langle x,y \rangle= \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n \bar{y_n}$. Define a linear functional $f:c_{00} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{n}$. If $N$ is the kernel of $f$. Prove the following:
>
> $(A)$ $||f|| \leq \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6}}$
>
> $(B)$ $N^{\perp}= \{0\}$

How do I do this? I am a little rusty in functional analysis. I have looked up the required definitions but am confused as to how to proceed. Help!

Comment: @Aweygan Yes that is correct

Answer (score 2):

Part (A) follows directly from Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

For part (B): Choose any $(y_n)\in N^\perp$. Then we know that there exists a natrual number $m$ such that $y_n=0$ for all $n>m$. Now let $k\leq m$ and $k'>m$, define the sequence $(x_n)$ by
$$x_n=\begin{cases}k, &n=k\\
-k', &n=k'\\
0, &\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$
Then by straight forward computation we can see that $(x_n)\in N$, and 
$$0=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n\overline{y_n}=x_k\overline{y_k}=k\overline{y_k},$$
thus we have $y_k=0$. As $k\leq m$ is arbitrary we conclude that $y_k=0$ for all $k\leq m$. Therefore $y_n=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, which means $N^\perp=\{0\}$.